# Can the meta/cmd key be shown in a shortcut?

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I am trying to add a shortcut to a menu item in my Qt application. I did this using this code:

```
ui->menuActionConnect->setShortcut(QKeySequence("Meta+D"));
```

When I run the application, OSX displays the meta key as the ctrl key (`^` instead of `⌘`):
[image: Here you can see that the wrong character is being displayed]

Is there a way to get Qt to display the `⌘` character instead of the `^` character? I have tried replacing `Meta` with `Cmd`, but this did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Ctrl` key to get the command key on Mac.

On Mac, `Ctrl` maps to the command keys and `Meta` maps to control keys.
On Windows, `Ctrl` maps to the control keys and `Meta` maps to the windows key.

See the [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#Modifier-enum).

Comment: I knew it'd be a simple solution!